# How to open Google Cached version of a URL

Tags: google-search

I have a URL http://raw.fotosite.pl/ which seems broken. I want to view its cached version if cached by Google/any other web caching site.

1. In Google advanced search is there any special keyword/search directive that I can use to find the cached version of this site.
2. Is there any other site which caches web pages and displays back dated versions of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify a URL to get a Google cached version of page?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15633/how-to-modify-a-url-to-get-a-google-cached-version-of-page)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The query `cache:url` will display
>   Google’s cached version of a web page,
>   instead of the current version of the
>   page. For example, [
>   [cache:www.eff.org](http://www.google.com/search?q=cache%3awww.eff.org) ] will show
>   Google’s cached version of the
>   Electronic Frontier Foundation home
>   page.
>
> Note: Do not put a space between
>   cache: and the URL (web address).

However, when I try the web site you referred, Google does not open any cached version. That must be because Google has not been caching that site. However, it brings a cached version if you use `cache:www.fotosite.pl` instead of `cache:raw.fotosite.pl`.

Comment: There is a bookmarklet here - http://moz.com/blog/30-seo-bookmarklets-to-save-you-time called "GG Text Cache" that can be used to avoid typing out the query each time. Once you've accessed the original URL click on the bookmarklet and it will run the cache:url query with the URL inserted & redirect you to the cached page.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [internet wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/) to get different versions of the site's past.

Comment: There is also http://archive.is.

Answer (score 2):

When you search for the page in Google, normally Google will give a hyperlink under all search results as 'Cached'. clicking that, opens the cached version.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be doing this any more.