# How to modify a URL to get a Google cached version of page?

Tags: google-search

I want to look at a Google cached version of a webpage, but can't find it through the usual mechanisms, as per this [related question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14878/how-to-open-google-cached-version-of-a-url).

Is there a way to modify the URL in the address bar to take me to the last cached page for a specific URL?

Comment: Do you mean the cache ID ? because there is a cached page for the first page mentioned.

Comment: @phwd,  I searched for hours and couldn't find the cached page.  What I would like is a mechanism to modify some Google URL to give me the cached page, which would probably involve the cache ID.

Comment: The answer in related question does work - provided you use Chrome, however. fwiw link to the cached page http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cache%3Awww.frontsightproshop.com%2Fcatalog%2Fitem%2F6395190%2F6218773.htm

Comment: @Sathya, wow, that was the exact day I wanted it for also.  So why does Chrome do better getting Google caches than other browsers?

Comment: I think this was more of a case where the page was not cached by Google at the time you searched. I'll spend some time later trying to find how `cache:<url>` works in Chrome - if nothing Chromium sources should highlight what it's doing.

Comment: in Chrome you can use this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache/bnmfcdcicagaffaokphooddegagehcin?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon  ...just click this button to view cached version of current webpage

Comment: Related: [How can I bring back the Google “cached version” links?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/20173/7584)

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can access the cached version for any page that has been saved by Google with this:

```
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://example.com/
```

Change **http://example.com/** to any URL. You can also create a [custom search engine on Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95426?hl=en&rd=1) or a [Firefox keyword](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Using_keyword_searches#Creating_bookmarks_with_keywords) to go to cached versions automatically by adding a keyword before the current URL address.

Comment: +1; also works without the `http://` prefix; curiously, there is at least one URL that doesn't work, however: `http://www.cnn.com/`; any idea why?: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.cnn.com/ (variations without `http://` and `www` don't work either).

Comment: @mklement0: That's because CNN doesn't allow it.

Comment: You can put 'cache:' before the url in firefox to get the same result.

Comment: @SomeNickName You use Google as your default search engine, so all that Firefox did was perform a Google search for `cache:http://example.com/`, which redirects to the cached page (as pointed out by [the other answer on this page](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/15669/14334)). This would "work" on any browser with Google as the default search engine. However, my solution will work even if you use other search engines, and it goes straight to the cached page instead of going through the Google search redirection.

Comment: @screener I didn't know it used the default search engine, i thought it was a firefox feature like chrome has... sorry.

Answer (score 39):

If you use Google Chrome, just use this query to get the cache page from Google:

```
cache:http://www.example.net/
```

For example you can use:

```
cache:http://www.example.com/catalog/item/6395190/8298122.htm
```

in Google search to find the corresponding cache page.

Comment: Both methods above now seem to result in a 404

Comment: agreed, all versions of this 'fix' result in Google 404. i love how Google has a cache cause it can see the text and gives you the picture sniplet to the right but no way to blow up the webpage to read the entire cached version--completely useless. There has to be a way..

Comment: I tried this and the search isn't triggered. Mmmm, this is odd (tried with other URLs aswell)

Comment: I still use this to get cached versions in Chrome: `cache:http://example.com`

Comment: This is brilliant.

Comment: TRY THIS 2023. A very good cache website:  https://cachedview.com/